# freetext search in dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I want to use freetext search against the dbpedia and I'm trying the query I found on the W3C website: https://www.w3.org/2009/Talks/0615-qbe/

If I try the query WITHOUT the bif: prefix by commenting it out I get the error shown below the query:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
# PREFIX bif: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/bif#>
SELECT ?lbl ?est
WHERE {
  ?country rdfs:label ?lbl .
  FILTER(bif:contains(?lbl, "Republic")) .
  ?country a type:Country108544813 ;
      prop:establishedDate ?est .
  FILTER(?est < "1920-01-01"^^xsd:date) .
}
```

Error: Line 9, Parse error: namespace mapping for "bif" not defined
       when expanding QName "bif:contains".
[condition type: sparql-lexer-error-namespace-mapping-not-defined]

well: that makes sense, you do need to define your namespace. So let me do the same query again using the bif: prefix that I found on the Virtuoso website (and various other places)

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX bif: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/bif#>
SELECT ?lbl ?est
WHERE {
  ?country rdfs:label ?lbl .
  FILTER(bif:contains(?lbl, "Republic")) .
  ?country a type:Country108544813 ;
      prop:establishedDate ?est .
  FILTER(?est < "1920-01-01"^^xsd:date) .
}
```

Now I get a different error: it seems that the bif: namespace is a protected name by Virtuoso

[image]

So it seems I cannot live with bif: or without :bif. Has anyone seen this error before? Thanks.

Btw: I really don't care that much about bif: What I really want is to do freetext queries against dbpedia. So any alternative is welcome. YES: there are earlier questions on SO about this but note that each of those answers contain bif: as well.

Added later: so just to be sure I changed bif: into bof: and now I get a new error that shows that contains no longer is a valid operator. See below. So anyway: I guess the only thing I care about from here on is: how do you do freetext queries against dbpedia :-)

[image]

Comment: Are you using [tag:dotnetrdf]? Try  `PREFIX bif: <bif:>`.

Comment: or use it as proper triple pattern: `?lbl bif:contains "Republic"`.

Comment: I have tried without success to find where you found `PREFIX bif: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/bif#>`, as I would like to correct any such...  Can you provide a pointer?

Comment: Stanislav: I'm using Gruff to connect to dbpedia and our pre processor barfed on bif:  your suggestion for the prefix worked

Answer (score 0):

`bif:` is a Virtuoso built-in, for "built-in function".

You're going through some sort of SPARQL pre-parser, not directly against the SPARQL endpoint, so you do need to define the prefix in your query.  Most such pre-parsers will do the right thing if you just --

```
PREFIX  bif:  <bif:>
```

Alternatively, you can change your query from using the `bif:contains` function --

```
FILTER(bif:contains(?lbl, "Republic"))
```

-- to use SPARQL regex --

```
FILTER regex(?lbl, "Republic")
```

Comment: Your suggestion Prefix bif: <bif:> did the trick. Your suggestion to use FILTER(bif:contains(?lbl, "Republic")) also did the trick. Thank you very much TallTed

Comment: You asked  where I found the bif URI: I found it on StackOverflow. Google for where is bif: URI

Comment: @JansAasman - Please click to ACCEPT the answer. Also worth noting, we (I work for OpenLink Software) are addressing the `bif:` URI expansion. Starting soon, all future versions of Virtuoso should accept `bif:` without prefix declaration (so old queries won't break) as well as `PREFIX bif: <bif:>` or `PREFIX bif: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/bif#>` (so all pre-parsers should work as well as direct interaction).